# Specify interface address as condition for nftables dnat rule

Tags: nat, nftables

I have three interfaces:

- lan0: 192.168.1.1
- dmz0: 192.168.2.1
- wan0: 192.168.3.123

wan0 receives its IP through DHCP. I'd like to create a dnat rule for tcp ports 80 and 443 which should match on any traffic where the original destination is wan0's IP, even if the packet does not arrive on wan0. The rule should of course not match for traffic which was not originally destined for this host. Is this possible?

I've tried to adding the dnat rule to a chain using the input hook, but this doesn't seem to be supported, despite [the documentation](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Netfilter_hooks) seemingly claiming otherwise.